# Can't bake normal map

Tags: uv, texture-baking, baking, normal-map

I have two meshes: one is low poly which also has uv map and another one is high poly mesh.

[image]

And also I created new image for baking normalmap from uv/image editor.

In the render tab, I choosed "Normals" and checked "Selected to Active".

Those both meshes are in the same location with same scale/rotation.

Finally select **high poly first** and select low poly later and click bake, but result is just same as low poly mesh.

Sometimes it just didn't baked with weird error message that something like "Circular blabla", so I created new texture image in the texture tab and then it works but still result is not coming from high poly mesh.

[image]

I don't know somehow, only once I've succeed, but after I tried to reprocess, it never succeed. I'm already tried this over 10 times more but still stuck here.

I sawed and read hundreds of videos and articles about baking normalmap in blender, but none of one is working to me.

Using Blender 2.78c also tried with 2.79 but didn't worked either. Why this is happening?

p.s. Additionally, I just baked Ambient Occlusion map and it looks fine. Seems only normal map doesn't baked properly.

Comment: If you had "Circular reference in texture stack" then the same texture baking is done to was used for material. Where did you create a new texture? What is "texture tab"? Is the texture shown on the screenshot the same faces of the mesh are assigned to? (As this appears to be Blender Internal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is baking the displacement map. Baking normal map for that mesh doesn't work because the tangent value is undefined, meaning your mesh has shaped 90 degree difference of angel (as we always know tan 90 is undefined). However, if you make slight difference, say it shaped 89.99, it might work. The point is never make an angle difference that makes its tanget value is undefined

Comment: I know what you are getting at, but I highly doubt the OP knows what you mean. You might want to try to explain it without the tangent references.

Comment: Ok I just baked Displacement map, but it isn't normal. How can I use this as normalmap? Is there a way to convert this?